# How to have a HTML submit form for ChatGPT4?

Tags: html, chatgpt

I can create a html submit form for Google, example:

```
<form action="https://www.google.com/search" method="get">
    <input type="text" name="q" placeholder="Search Google">
    <input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
```

it works, it is great!

**The Question:** how can I create the same, for ChatGPT4? (I have a plus subscription)

If I try with something like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Chat with ChatGPT-4</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="https://chat.openai.com/backend-api/conversation" method="post">
        <h1>Chat with ChatGPT-4</h1>
        
        <label for="message">Your message:</label><br>
        <input type="text" id="message" name="message" required><br>
        
        <input type="submit" value="Send">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

All I get back is a:

```
{"detail":{"message":"Unauthorized - Access token is missing"}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the error message is correct. You need to go to the [developer portal for ChatGPT](https://www.makeuseof.com/chatgpt-api-complete-guide/) ([Javascript example](https://rollbar.com/blog/chatgpt-api-with-javascript/)) this will allow you to create an API key that you can use to access the API.

Your form will need to run some js that submits a message the ChatGPT API. Preferably on a server, since anyone can "borrow" your API key and use it as if it were you if you place the chatGPT code on a webpage.